# Does output redirection to a block device overwrite bytes or whole blocks?

Tags: io-redirection, block-device

A [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484060/can-dev-zero-wipe-out-partition-tables/484063#comment886813_484062) on another question made me wonder:

Assuming I redirect the output from a command to a block device, and the length of that output is less than the block size of the block device:

```
% blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda
4096

% head -c 100 /dev/zero > /dev/sda
```

Will that overwrite the first 100 bytes of /dev/sda, or the first 4096 bytes (i.e. one complete block)?
Does the behaviour depend on the shell, output buffering settings, or even the *nix flavour (which might use character devices instead of block devices, like *BSD)?

Comment: Are you mixing blocks and sectors?

Answer (score 1):

If you write to a block device using some size N that is smaller than the underlying block size, then I'd expect the OS to (1) read a full block from the device, (2) update the first N blocks (assuming a zero offset) with what you're writing, and (3) re-write the entire block to the device.  The end result would be that it would appear to have written the first N bytes.

Comment: Why should the fs read the block(s) (unless the fd is open read-write)?

Comment: @RudiC Because a block device, as the name implies, operates on "blocks" -- a "block" is the smallest unit that you can read/write.  If you want to modify less than an entire block, you read the block, modify the applicable portion, then re-write the block.

Comment: Not if the redirector is `>`, for example. Or any other "write only" ("create") opening, I'd guess.

Comment: @RudiC Any non-block-size, non-block-aligned write

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience with `dd`, at least some software writes only the specified number of bytes (and not complete blocks). For example, it is possible to write to the very head end of a drive to modify the BIOS boot sector (MBR) and the partition table.

But it is possible that some other software is made to write whole blocks.

I suggest that you test how a particular program behaves (or ask for help to test it).